# maths required to complete project euler

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, project-euler

What maths will help one complete most if not all of project Euler questions? Last I've attempted project Euler I could not understand the questions/vocabulary, etc., and could only complete a few questions. I've gone over set theory, and college algebra and looking through the questions again they are more comprehensible.

I'd assume knowledge of discrete maths will help most with project Euler questions?

Comment: It's been years since I've looked at it, but I remember number theory playing a large role.

Comment: Number theory, or good at cooking up nice algorithms. Some are also not that math'ish but some knowledge about graph theory is needed like how to find Hamilton path (or at least knowing how to use computer to help you to do so).

Comment: The main thing is that they want you to do the questions in order, learning for each by experimentation, particularly with your own computer programs for testing ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One text I'd recommend highly, and it will give you a very solid foundation in Discrete Math, and more, is Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's [Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025).

From the description available at the link above:

> This book introduces the mathematics that supports advanced computer programming and the analysis of algorithms. The primary aim of its well-known authors is to provide a solid and relevant base of mathematical skills - the skills needed to solve complex problems, to evaluate horrendous sums, and to discover subtle patterns in data.... Concrete Mathematics is a blending of CONtinuous and disCRETE mathematics....
>
> ...The book includes more than 500 exercises, divided into six categories. Complete answers are provided for all exercises, except research problems, making the book particularly valuable for self-study. Major topics include: *Sums *Recurrences *Integer functions *Elementary number theory *Binomial coefficients *Generating functions *Discrete probability *Asymptotic methods